# Converting string to Date Object with default backup Python

Tags: python, date

Currently I convert a string date in the format 18-Jan-2017 to date object using the following line of code.

```
applicationdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(appdate, '%d-%b-%Y').date()
```

I would like it to default to None/Null/Empty if the conversion fails. What would be the most efficient way to do this thats also easy to read?

Comment: wrap it in a `try... except`... catch the `ValueError`... process as needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `try`/`except`:

```
try:
    applicationdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(appdate, '%d-%b-%Y').date()
except ValueError:
    # handle error? log warning?
    applicationdate = None
```

Some other languages shy away from using exceptions for flow control, but in Python it's efficient, readable and usually considered best practice.